# could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgis

I want to enable postgis in my empty database

```
psql --version # psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg16.04+1)
sudo -u postgres psql 
\c lom
lom=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory
```

It looks like postgis was installed

```
apt-cache search postgresql-13-postgis
postgresql-13-postgis-2.5 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13
postgresql-13-postgis-2.5-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13 -- SQL scripts
postgresql-13-postgis-3 - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13
postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 13 -- SQL scripts
```

I was trying to install utility modules

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-13-postgis-3=3.1.4+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1 postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts=3.1.4+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.1.4+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1' for 'postgresql-13-postgis-3' was not found
E: Version '3.1.4+dfsg-1.pgdg20.04+1' for 'postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts' was not found
```

Also was trying to restart postgres

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Comment: As far as I know, `apt search` searches the packages you can install, not only the ones that are installed. Use `dpkg -L` to see what is installed.

Answer (score 0):

From the ERROR it looks like there are still few functions remain installed in postgres with older postgis version.

You can do some cleaup to remove version 2 PostGIS extension:

- Check number of objects left over from version 2 PostGIS:

> postgres=> `SELECT probin, count(*) FROM pg_proc WHERE probin LIKE '%postgis%' GROUP BY probin;`
> probin         | count
> -----------------------+-------
> $libdir/postgis-2.3   |   436
> $libdir/rtpostgis-2.3 |   107

- Try dropping PostGIS extension with cascade option:

> `DROP EXTENSION postgis CASCADE;` (this might result in failure, but just to verify)

If dropping extension doesn't work then you have to DROP all functions manually listed in:

> `select proname FROM pg_proc WHERE probin = '$libdir/postgis-2.2';`

> `DROP FUNCTION function_name;`   and you should be good.

Comment: WARNING: `DROP EXTENSION postgis CASCADE;` will drop geometries from your tables.